# Read data from column and row after clicking gridview button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which has gridview buttons for each generated row. When i click the the button it sends an email to the user but I need to be able to read one of the column(WHERE column) and its  row  value and  include it in the body of my message

Here is my markup code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"        onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    DataSourceID="prmtest" Width="994px" BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#4D5763" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name_of_Training" HeaderText="Name of training" 
            SortExpression="Name_of_Training" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Date" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Column1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Start_time" HeaderText="Start time" 
            SortExpression="Start_time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="End_time" HeaderText="End time" 
            SortExpression="End_time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Where" 
            SortExpression="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Seats" HeaderText="Available seats" SortExpression="Seats" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Training documents" 
        NavigateUrl="url.zip" Text="Training material" Target="_self">
        <ItemStyle ForeColor="#E5003B"    Font-Underline="false"/>
    </asp:HyperLinkField>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Book"
             OnClientClick="alert('The booking will be made for?')" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"
                Text="Book" />
        </ItemTemplate>
            <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#4D5763" BackColor="#DCDFE2" />
    <EditRowStyle Font-Underline="False" />
</asp:GridView>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="prmtest" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbprmtest %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT [Name of Training] AS Name_of_Training, 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Date],20), [Start time] AS Start_time, [End time] AS End_time, [Location], [Seats] FROM [Sheet1$]">
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is my email code

```
    if (e.CommandName == "Book")
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add("email@test.com");
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("email2@test.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Test";
            mailMessage.Body = "";
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.text.com;
            smtpClient.Host = "test.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 25;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test.test", "password");
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            btnemail.Text = "E-mail  and Booking sent!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
            lblemail.Text = "Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to this:

First Method is to send the data that you need in the CommandArguement. Like:

```
CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex.ToString() +"|" + Eval("Anything").ToString() %>'
```

| symbol is used as a separator here. You can then split the string using the separator symbol like:

```
var arguements = CommandArguement.ToString().Split('|');
```

Second Method is to go to the row by using the row index and search for elements you would like to have in the mail.

Answer (score 0):

In you "oncommand" event handler, first find the "owner" of the grid row that contains to button

```
Button btn = (sender as Button);
GridViewRow grv = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
```

GridRowView then gives you access to the row (DataItemIndex) in the underlying data source which you can then pull any/all fields from using below

```
DataView dview = (DataView)prmtest.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
string str = (string)dview[grv.DataItemIndex]["Location"];
```

Alternatively, if it is literally just the location you need, then maybe something as simple as this.

```
Button btn = (sender as Button);
GridViewRow grv = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

string str = gvAssets.Rows[grv.DataItemIndex].Cells[4].Text;   // Cell[4] being the Location Col.
```

HTH...

Comment: I am not sure i understand do i now have to create another button as the email code is placed in a Row_Command.